# Find the set of values of x for which $\frac{x+1}{2x-3}<\frac{1}{x-3}$

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Here's what I've done:

$\frac{x+1}{2x-3}<\frac{1}{x-3}$

$x+1<\frac{2x-3}{x-3}$

$(x+1)(x-3)<2x-3$

$x^2-2x-3<2x-3$

$x^2-4x<0$

$x(x-4)<0$

$0<x<4$

However this clearly fails because when $x$ is $2$, for example, the inequality fails.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: When $x = 2$, you have that $x-3 < 0$. What happens when you multiply both sides of an inequality by a negative number?

Answer (score 3):

Beware of cross-multiplying when solving inequalities! You might be multiplying by a negative number – which would invalidate the inequality.

One way to proceed is to bring everything to one side and simplify:

$\quad\quad\quad\dfrac{x+1}{2x+3}\ <\ \dfrac1{x-3}$

$\implies\ 0\ <\ \dfrac1{x-3}-\dfrac{x+1}{2x+3}$

$\implies\ 0\ <\ \dfrac{2x+3-(x+1)(x-3)}{(x-3)(2x+3)}$

…etc.

Answer (score 0):

Taking in account the comment of @SteamyRoot and resolve it again, you will have the answer $x\in I=]0,\frac{3}{2}[~\cup~]3,4[$.

Clearly the example you have taken ($x=2$) doesn't belong to I.

Comment: You can obtain the union symbol $\cup$ by typing \cup when you are in math mode.  You can obtain the intersection symbol $\cap$ by typing \cap when you are in math mode.  For more information, read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.